# Where can I find compiler info to verify & publish an ERC-20 token on Etherscan when I didn't write the code?

Tags: ether, erc-20, etherscan

I'm a developer working for a small startup with a standard ERC-20 token that we'd like to verify on Etherscan, but I wasn't the person who minted the tokens initially (that developer no longer works for the company).

I'm not familiar with Solidity, and am not sure how to find the information we need to verify and publish according to Etherscan's requirements.

**How do I figure out what compiler type and compiler version were used to mint the tokens?**

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the code of ERC20 that's deployed?  If so isn't the version mentioned within itself?

Comment: I was just able to find it and it did include the version, but still having trouble getting the contract verified on Etherscan and trying to figure out why.  Thanks for the comment!

Comment: happy it was helpful. no prob :)

Answer (score 0):

Is the token already deployed on main Ethereum Network? try searching https://etherscan.io using the token address if you have it.
have a look at  [this](https://steemit.com/ethereum/@maxnachamkin/how-to-create-your-own-ethereum-token-in-an-hour-erc20-verified) Steemit post.